# Warning: imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in Drupal

Tags: image, drupal, thumbnails

I install a new drupal. When i create a content for article ,the picture doesn't general the thumb .And the recent log show 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please check if `sites/default/files` is writable by www-data.

Comment: Please check http://huashuo520.cn/admin/reports/status for any errors or warnings and fix them.

Comment: my php runner is webuser .so sites/default/files is webuser and the Permission is 777

Answer (score 2):

Your GD is missing the JPEG support. If you are installing PHP in a docker env you need to install libjpeg-dev, libfreetype6-dev and

```
docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/
```

If you are using PHP in any hosting-env, talk to your hosting provider. Mine looks like

```
gd

GD Support => enabled
GD Version => bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
FreeType Support => enabled
FreeType Linkage => with freetype
FreeType Version => 2.6.3
GIF Read Support => enabled
GIF Create Support => enabled
JPEG Support => enabled
libJPEG Version => 6b
PNG Support => enabled
libPNG Version => 1.6.28
WBMP Support => enabled
XBM Support => enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-jpeg=/usr/include/ --with-freetype=/usr/include/
```

with php 7.4

Answer (score 0):

If like me, you're also running into this issue with `PHP 7.4`, this is what helped me solve it (found it in Drupal issue [comments](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3116611#comment-13893088))

#### Setup :

- Docker compose v3
- Drupal 9 loaded in a php:7.4-apache container

#### Solution :

Dockerfile for Drupal container :

```
...
# installs lib dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev

# configure and install gd with jpeg/freetype enabled
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-jpeg --with-freetype \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd
...
```

#### Verification :

And, to make sure the extension is correctly configured and installed, type the following in your container shell :

```bash
php -i
```

Find gd extension :

```
gd

GD Support => enabled
GD Version => bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
FreeType Support => enabled
FreeType Linkage => with freetype
FreeType Version => 2.10.4
GIF Read Support => enabled
GIF Create Support => enabled
JPEG Support => enabled
libJPEG Version => 6b
PNG Support => enabled
libPNG Version => 1.6.37
WBMP Support => enabled
XBM Support => enabled
BMP Support => enabled
TGA Read Support => enabled
```

If `JPEG Support => enabled` and `FreeType Support => enabled` are in the list, you should be good to go : )